# Change csv.writer(open()) - Python to PySpark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to apply a function made in Python, to be readable on [PySpark](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/index.htm).

The open() function is not readable in PySpark. How can I replace in this case?

And I have an unstructured list of lists that needs to be sorted:

```py
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
my_list = [
        [3, 'ab','ac','ad'],
        [4, 'ae','af','at','aj','aa'],
        [1, 'ar','aa','at','as'],
        [2, 'ay','au','aa','ar','aa','a1']
        ]
# Sorting this list:
sorted_list =  sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter(0))
```

This is the function working in Python that I need to change:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w', newline='') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|')
      wr.writerows(sorted_list)
```

I was unable to use this function below, because of the unstructured type of the list of lists:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_list)
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark_df.write.csv("file.txt".format(root),sep="|", mode='overwrite', quote="\u0000")
```

Is there a workaround in Python or PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment just yet, but I would like to say that for unstructured data you could opt for a Spark RDD.

When you instantiate your SparkSession you can then retrieve the Spark Context. For example, assuming you properly instantiated your instance:

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

You can then convert your sorted list into an RDD, as such:

```
sorted_RDD = sc.parallelize(sorted_list)
```

From there you could run the saveAsSingleTextFile method to write to a textfile.

```
sorted_RDD.saveAsSingleTextFile(<output_dir>)
```

Now, I am not sure if you have any sort of further processing. The other option that you can do is figure out the maximum size of the list and then create a dataframe with null values to create an even size. It really all depends on what you want to extract from this data.

**Please note that I used saveAsSingleTextFile() method because I assume that you want this stored as a single text file. If you want to split this file up, which is usually recommended for larger datasets, you can do saveAsTextFile().